# How can I parse the JSON response and could get value from known key as output?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

My code is as below, I tried using JSONOption but it did not work

```
Response res =  (Response) RestAssured.given().queryParam("CUSTOMER_ID","68195").queryParam("PASSWORD","1234!").queryParam("Account_No","1").get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/sinkministatement.php").then().extract().response();
System.out.println(res.body().asString());
        
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(res.prettyPrint());
       System.out.println(jsonBody);
```

I can get JSON Body with PreetyPrint method but could not fetch key-value pair from that response. Seems like I need to parse output of body method .

Answer (score 0):

There is a command tool called [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) and JS implementation at https://github.com/fiatjaf/jq-web.

Sample usage:

```
var jq = require('jq-web')
var result = jq.json({...}, 'select(.CUSTOMER_ID="123")');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try HttpClient's GetMethod.

```
private static HttpClient httpClient;
       
    public void getTest() {
          GetMethod request = new GetMethod("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/sinkministatement.php" +
                "?CUSTOMER_ID=68195" + 
                "&PASSWORD=1234" +
                "&Account_No=1");
            try {
                int result = httpClient.executeMethod(request);
                String responseContent = request.getResponseBodyAsString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```